# Chrome extension that would stream Youtube music (no video)

Tags: chrome, youtube

I know I can use dedicated music service: grooveshark, spotify, rdio, pandora, last.fm, soundcloud...

However, if I were to use Youtube in some scenarios to preserve bandwidth I would like to stream music part only (no video).

Just asking, maybe you know such extension.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm  not entirely sure you can do this but you can always download the videos in audio format.

[Fetchaudio](http://fetchaudio.com/) is a good website. It is quite simple to use and you can download YouTube videos in audio only online which is pretty good. Another service you could use is [keepvid.com](http://keepvid.com/). You can also download YouTube videos in audio format.

I used them quite frequently, but my preference would be fetchaudio.com. Also see this related question [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15603/disable-videos-in-youtube-listen-to-the-audio-only) and do let me know if this works or not. :)

Answer (score 1):

[AudioOnlyYoutube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/audio-only-youtube/pkocpiliahoaohbolmkelakpiphnllog/related) is a Chrome extension that disables video in YouTube videos

Answer (score 0):

https://www.listenvideo.com seems to work quite well, I have not tried it extensively though. There is also [off-browser app support](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/listen-video-youtube-musi/cbiapabbjlfcbfoedilflhnifandagoh?hl=en).

Answer (score -1):

[Streamus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/streamus/jbnkffmindojffecdhbbmekbmkkfpmjd?hl=en) is a Chrome extension that allows you to stream music from Youtube.